# Changing table row color per two rows

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I have an HTML table and would like to change the row color every two rows, for two rows at a time. I don't mean selecting every other row using `nth-child(even)`, which is all I keep seeing in my search engine results. I'm trying to set the background color of rows 1 and 2, then 5 and 6, then 9 and 10...and so on, leaving the other rows with the default white background.

I've tried using `:nth-child(2n+b)` and I don't think it's possible using that pseudo-selector. The tables are dynamically generated and will fluctuate in row count, so hard coding is not an option.

Is there some sort of JavaScript way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's definitely possible using CSS's `:nth-child()` notation:

```
tr:nth-child(4n + 1) td,
tr:nth-child(4n + 2) td {
    background-color: #ffa;
}

tr:nth-child(4n + 3) td,
tr:nth-child(4n + 4) td {
    background-color: #f90;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4tSq9/).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed - didn't even think of using multiple `nth-child`s in one rule. Thank you, David.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for your problem in php. Hope you can convert it into your required javascript.

```
$n = "#666";

$c = 0;

$p = 0;

while($c < 9){

if($p%2 == 0){

$n = ($n == "#666")?"#FFF":"#666";

$p=0;

}

$c++;

}
```

Comment: Do you have a bit of a type in your opening of the `while` loop? I'm sure you're missing a `)` and a `{`? That said, this is in the wrong language entirely.

Comment: sorry that was misplaced. Here you gives the condition until your loop will continue like $c < 9